# listen for event's from clients by laravel-echo-server

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

i want to build something like chat system ,
but i don't  want Laravel or Database to involve for some requests.

i want to send message from client to laravel-echo-server and then laravel-echo-server broadcasts that message to all users.

if I emit using this `window.Echo.connector.socket.emit` how to listen on it in `laravel-echo-server`?

is there any solution for this?